# Simple Dynamics Question?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Two books are resting side by side, in contact, on a desk. An applied horizontal force of 0.58N causes the books to move together with an acceleration of 0.21m/s/s horizontally. The mass of the book to which the force is applied directly is 1.0kg. Neglecting friction, determine:

a.) the mass of the other book

b.) the magnitude of the force exerted by one book on the other.

Attempt:

Force is applied on Box A Box A applies force on Box B

Fnet = Fapp + F(BonA)
ma = (0.58 N) + F(BonA)
F(BonA) = -0.3 N
F(BonA) = -F(AonB)

F(AonB) = 0.3 N

Fnet = Fapp + FAonB

m(0.21) = 0.58 - 0.3

m = 1.33 kg

a) The correct answer is 1.8 kg..am i doing something wrong? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Total mass = $\frac{F_{net}}{a_{net}}$. Internal forces can then be found by $F=ma$ on individual bodies.